# PostgreSQL 13 + Hibernate 6.0.2 + wildfly-preview-27.0.0.Alpha5 Error

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have to configure my PostgreSQL datasource for WildFly in order to use it in my Jakarta EE 10 with hibernate 6.0.2

Below shown are my configuration

**Postgresql module in widfly**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

**Datasource**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/nextu" pool-name="nextu">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nextu</connection-url>
    <driver>postgres</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>nextu</user-name>
        <password>nextu</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

**Driver used**

> org.postgresql.Driver

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/nextu</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <!-- AUTO-GENERATES DATABASE FROM ANNOTATIONS METADATA -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source"  value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error I am getting while running:**

> 00:50:49,304 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 80) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.persistenceunit."servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#primary":
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.persistenceunit."servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#primary":
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
> org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.0.Alpha5//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:199)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.0.Alpha5//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Beta3//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.0.Alpha5//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.contributeTypes(PostgreSQLDialect.java:1107)
> at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:374)
> at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:144)
> at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350)
> at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421)
> at
> org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate6@27.0.0.Alpha5//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:45)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.0.Alpha5//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
> ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
> initialize PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:78)
> ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.postgresql.util.PGInterval.getWholeSeconds() at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2675) at
> org.hibernate@6.0.2.Final//org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:74)
> ... 17 more
>
> 00:50:49,307 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
> address: ([("deployment" => "servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) -
> failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.persistenceunit."servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#primary"" =>
> "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize
> PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.postgresql.util.PGInterval.getWholeSeconds()"}} 00:50:49,360 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010:
> Deployed "servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name :
> "servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war") 00:50:49,361 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183:
> Service status report WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:
> service jboss.persistenceunit."servlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#primary":
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError WFLYCTL0448: 11 additional
> services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
> 00:50:49,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
> WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server 00:50:49,410 ERROR [org.jboss.as]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Preview 27.0.0.Alpha5
> (WildFly Core 19.0.0.Beta15) started (with errors) in 9738ms - Started
> 412 of 658 services (13 services failed or missing dependencies, 362
> services are lazy, passive or on-demand) - Server configuration file
> in use: standalone.xml

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I had PostgreSQL dependencies in my pom maven.This is the code added.

```
<plugins>
         <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
          <configuration>
          <archive>
             <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>org.postgres</Dependencies>
             </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
       </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

NB : org.postgres  => the name of my module Postgres previously define in widfly.

Comment: thanks for that. I had the same problem with a persistence unit inside ear/war. It was a wiered timing problem. sometimes the org.posgresql module was loaded before war/ear and somethimes not. After the entry in pom.xml like you propagated this is working correct for at least 30 restarts :)